# Getting permission denied error when I run "gem install bundler"

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm setting up my environment to run Cucumber/Rspec with Ruby and Capybara.

However, when I run the command "sudo gem install bundler" the error below is being returned:

```
Permission denied @ rb_sysopen
```

I've seen lots of answers for this problem on Google however still not working.

Could you guys help me?

Technical info

```
- Mac
- ruby 2.3.7
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.3
```

Output

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - 
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/CHANGELOG.md
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add or link to the solutions you have already tried?

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Which version of Ruby? Which version of RubyGems are you using?

Comment: Can you post the full command line output starting with "gem install bundler"?

Comment: Hi guys, here are the infos
- Mac
- ruby 2.3.7
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.3

Comment: Install RVM with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`; restart your shell; install Ruby with `rvm install 2.6.0`. [Don't](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/psa-do-not-use-system-ruby) [use](https://chrisherring.co/posts/why-you-shouldn-t-use-the-system-ruby) [system Ruby](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2014/05/15/never-use-system-ruby-ever/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using the system's ruby and now you need to root level permission to to install bundler. Sudo enables root privileges. Check if your account has root privileges.

I prefer using a version and manager like [rbenv](http:////https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv). Install rbenv . then install the required version of ruby and then install bundler.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use ruby installers like `rvm.io` or `rbenv` to install ruby. You are using system ruby which needs root access of the system to install gems.